# Debugger in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

Silly question...

I cannot find the Debugger in XCode 4 (in 3 I could find it under one of the XCode menus in the menu bar); anyone knows where is it wondering?

Ohad

Comment: If you're new to Xcode 4 then [Where the F*** is _ in Xcode 4?](http://pilky.me/view/16) is definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debugger menu is under Product -> Debug

Answer (score 1):

Press the "Breakpoints" button in the top bar and run.

Answer (score 1):

Open your xCode-4 , Run your application with enabling some debug point.
Then **Press "command + 6"** ,

You will get the list of all debug point.